# The view music.views.detail didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django

My VIEW.PY file is:

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import render 
from .models import Album

def index(request):
all_albums = Album.objects.all()
return render(request, 'music/index.html', {'all_albums': all_albums})
def detail(request, album_id):
try:
  album = Album.objects.get(pk=album_id)
except Album.DoesNotExist:
  raise Http404("Album does not exist")
  return render(request, 'music/detail.html', {'album': album})'
```

DETAIL.HTML file is:

```
{{ album }}
```

I am getting error:

> The view music.views.detail didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Comment: Please indent your code correctly so the meaning is clear

Comment: indentation is required in my code and error is removed

Comment: Without correct indentation, this question can be closed as "unclear" or "no MCVE".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unident the return statement so that it is outside of the `except` block.

```
try:
    album = Album.objects.get(pk=album_id)
except Album.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404("Album does not exist")
return render(request, 'music/index.html', {'album': album})
```

Note that you can simplify your view slightly by using the `get_object_or_404` shortcut:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

def detail(request, album_id):
    album = get_object_or_404(Album, pk=album_id)
    return render(request, 'music/index.html', {'album': album})'
```